# Nuitka with Numpy fails "ImportError: LoadLibraryEx multiarray failed"

Tags: numpy, nuitka

I am trying to build an executable with Nuitka, for the following simple code:

```
from numpy import abs

var = raw_input("Please enter something: ")
print "you entered", var    
print abs(-43.2)

var2 = raw_input("Secundo: ")    
print var2
```

The Nuitka code I compile is:

```
nuitka --standalone --show-scons FILENAME
```

This is obviously a simplification of my problem. I tried compiling without numpy and without using "abs", and the exectuable executes perfectly. However, when I compile with the numpy code, and I try to execute the resulting .exe, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "...\__init__.dist\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\__init__.dist\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in numpy
  File "...\__init__.dist\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in add_newdocs
  File "...\__init__.dist\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in lib
  File "...\__init__.dist\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in type_check
  File "...\__init__.dist\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in core
ImportError: LoadLibraryEx '...\__init__.dist\numpy\core\multiarray.pyd' failed
```

I am using Python 2.7.8 64bit, Numpy 1.11.3 64bit, Nuitka 0.5.24.4

How can I solve this? Is Nuitka not compatible with Numpy?

The following is found in the **init**.dist folder:

```
│   bz2.pyd
│   gpsvc.dll
│   mfc90.dll
│   msvcr90.dll
│   msvcrt.dll
│   nlaapi.dll
│   python27.dll
│   pywintypes27.dll
│   sysntfy.dll
│   tree.txt
│   unicodedata.pyd
│   win32api.pyd
│   win32pdh.pyd
│   win32ui.pyd
│   _win32sysloader.pyd
│   __init__.exe
│   
└───numpy
    ├───core
    │       multiarray.pyd
    │       umath.pyd
    │       
    ├───fft
    │       fftpack_lite.pyd
    │       
    ├───linalg
    │       lapack_lite.pyd
    │       _umath_linalg.pyd
    │       
    └───random
            mtrand.pyd
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with `scipy`, I don't suppose you ever found a fix?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, but no I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

it is recommended to use `--plugin-enable=numpy` to fix this issue

So, in your case it would be something like this :

```
nuitka --standalone --show-scons --follow-import-to=numpy --plugin-enable=numpy FILENAME.py
```